# How to send iPhone app in background?

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone, background-process, mapkit

I want to create an app that work in background. In this first I allows from the user that this app work in background .

After this as the app will go in background that work efficiently and send me information which I want .

So , please tell me how I can execute this in my iPhone application.

Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Cp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [applicationDidEnterBackground](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground) method in your UIApplicationDelegate class to react to the event that your app is entering background. There's a corresponding willEnterForeground method.

What you can not do is to create an app whose sole purpose is to run in the background. There's no "start in background" action, from what I know you can't manually force an app to enter background while it's running. And unless you provide some useful user functionality in the app's user interface, Apple will not allow your app on the App Store.